# What calls NSTextInputClient-->attributedSubstringForProposedRange?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Some of our user crash reports show crashes in NSTextInputClient-->attributedSubstringForProposedRange. What OS X feature calls this code? I've tried the 'Character Viewer' and pressing 'Option+E' followed by 'E'.

This is the call stack (respondsToSelector at the top calls my view's attributedSubstringForProposedRange method):

```
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fd31e1 -[NSObject respondsToSelector:] + 52
  0   Lookup                              0x0ceb118c +[LUTextInputClientTextAccessor canAccessTextInView:] + 135
  0   Lookup                              0x0ceb10b4 +[LUTextInputClientTextAccessor canAccessTextAtLocation:] + 8
  0   Lookup                              0x0ceb10f6 +[LUTextInputClientTextAccessor canAccessTextAtLocation:] + 74
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea017e +[LUTextAccessor textAccessorForScreenLocation:] + 9
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea0322 +[LUTextAccessor textAccessorForScreenLocation:] + 429
  0   Lookup                              0x0cec6547 -[LUExtractor focusTermAndLocation:options:] + 9
  0   Lookup                              0x0cec66a1 -[LUExtractor focusTermAndLocation:options:] + 355
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb2ef lookUpMethod + 9
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea4336 __56+[LULookupDefinitionModule focusTermUsingQueue:handler:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea43d6 __56+[LULookupDefinitionModule focusTermUsingQueue:handler:]_block_invoke_0 + 172
  0   Foundation                          0x922681a7 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 12
  0   Foundation                          0x922682f0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 341
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea4336 __56+[LULookupDefinitionModule focusTermUsingQueue:handler:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
  0   Lookup                              0x0cea4396 __56+[LULookupDefinitionModule focusTermUsingQueue:handler:]_block_invoke_0 + 108
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x93580f8c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9357cc80 _dispatch_client_callout + 44
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x935822de _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 218
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b6c24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1956
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b648c __CFRunLoopRun + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b130 pthread_mutex_lock + 488
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fc3a14 flush_marked_caches + 9
  0   CarbonCore                          0x9463bd41 TSLockMutex + 225
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c184 szone_malloc_should_clear + 986
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915ffb9 malloc + 7
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c184 szone_malloc_should_clear + 986
  0   CarbonCore                          0x9463bc6c TSLockMutex + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bdb3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 9
  0   libxpc.dylib                        0x9971a10a _xpc_malloc + 21
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bdb3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f8d3 malloc_zone_calloc + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99161ad5 szone_calloc + 50
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f919 malloc_zone_calloc + 79
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99160037 calloc + 55
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9357d971 _dispatch_continuation_alloc_from_heap + 7
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9357d9ca _dispatch_continuation_alloc_from_heap + 96
  0   libxpc.dylib                        0x9971d4fb _xpc_services_unavailable + 9
  0   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9357d92e _dispatch_barrier_async_f_slow + 12
  0   libxpc.dylib                        0x9971d46c _xpc_runtime_extend_domain + 9
  0   libdyld.dylib                       0x960c54e4 tlv_load_notification + 9
  0   libxpc.dylib                        0x9971d5b0 xpc_dictionary_set_bool + 38
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bc5a tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 993
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b57f pthread_mutex_unlock + 287
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638a33a __CFGetConverter + 282
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c184 szone_malloc_should_clear + 986
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96389a66 __CFStringEncodeByteStream + 2406
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638910c __CFStringEncodeByteStream + 12
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfaa _ZN4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE16FindAndConstructERKS2_ + 28
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fd37b9 -[NSObject retain] + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fd3805 -[NSObject retain] + 85
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96380fa8 CFRetain + 8
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96381039 CFRetain + 153
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x964b4ba7 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1079
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x964b4779 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 9
  0   Foundation                          0x92215c71 _NSLookupOrCreateBundle + 12
  0   Foundation                          0x922160a5 _NSLookupOrCreateBundle + 1088
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9639cb55 CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation + 517
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bc5a tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 993
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f569 malloc_zone_malloc + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c12f szone_malloc_should_clear + 901
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963825a9 CFAllocatorAllocate + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96382723 __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate + 19
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bdb3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638123c _CFRetain + 476
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f569 malloc_zone_malloc + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99161a99 szone_malloc + 19
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f5a8 malloc_zone_malloc + 72
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96382162 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 3154
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963825a9 CFAllocatorAllocate + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96382723 __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate + 19
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963826f5 CFAllocatorAllocate + 341
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638b565 CFAllocatorGetDefault + 5
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963822e9 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963824a8 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 456
  0   Foundation                          0x92216a5e -[NSString isEqual:] + 68
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963820a3 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 2963
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638151c __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c12f szone_malloc_should_clear + 901
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b469 pthread_mutex_unlock + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bdb3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x9638e1d9 CFEqual + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f569 malloc_zone_malloc + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99161a99 szone_malloc + 19
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915f5a8 malloc_zone_malloc + 72
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x991626af szone_free + 2943
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96382723 __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate + 19
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916c162 szone_malloc_should_clear + 952
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbcbe9 _ZN4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE5eraseERKS2_ + 27
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916bdb3 szone_malloc_should_clear + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388d23 __CFAllocatorSystemDeallocate + 19
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x991626af szone_free + 2943
  0   CoreGraphics                        0x9925f4c1 shape_is_empty + 7
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbcbe9 _ZN4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE5eraseERKS2_ + 27
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388c29 CFAllocatorDeallocate + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388d23 __CFAllocatorSystemDeallocate + 19
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388d06 CFAllocatorDeallocate + 230
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388a65 CFRelease + 2037
  0   CoreGraphics                        0x99258d61 region_create_with_shape + 8
  0   CoreGraphics                        0x99261e55 shape_empty + 3
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x96388279 CFRelease + 9
  0   CoreGraphics                        0x9925f532 CGSReleaseRegion + 12
  0   QD                                  0x90a2703b QDFlushPortBuffer + 385
  0   QD                                  0x90a26cad QDIsPortBuffered + 11
  0   QD                                  0x90a26ec3 QDFlushPortBuffer + 9
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124b8d4 FlushPlatformWindow + 36
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124e314 _ZL17FlushWindowObjectP10WindowDataPPvh + 992
  0   HIToolbox                           0x91256f6c GetTaskStorageKeyForSafeToCall + 7
  0   HIToolbox                           0x91256cd5 _ZL15FlushAllBuffersP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 9
  0   HIToolbox                           0x91256dbc _ZL15FlushAllBuffersP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 240
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x99146052 pthread_threadid_np + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b130 pthread_mutex_lock + 488
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963dc7ee __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 478
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963dc65c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 76
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963dc619 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x964bb1f9 __addHandler2 + 9
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b6015 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 373
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b5fde CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 318
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b57f pthread_mutex_unlock + 287
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b5e86 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 118
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124ff55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 237
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124fbf0 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 157
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb2ef lookUpMethod + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbec1 object_getIndexedIvars + 21
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963c8a98 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 8
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963c8b51 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 193
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124fb5c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbaabc objc_msgSend + 76
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9124fb3f BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 83
  0   AppKit                              0x9385e935 _DPSNextEvent + 719
  0   AppKit                              0x9385e672 _DPSNextEvent + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915fd2d free + 214
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbca9b objc_destructInstance + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbcada objc_destructInstance + 72
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fc4f2a _object_dispose + 8
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fc4f61 _object_dispose + 63
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbd184 object_dispose + 6
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b141b -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 363
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x963b12bc -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916574a szone_free_definite_size + 2842
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbc1b6 _objc_rootReleaseWasZero + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbc21b _objc_rootReleaseWasZero + 110
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916574a szone_free_definite_size + 2842
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x991626af szone_free + 2943
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9916574a szone_free_definite_size + 2842
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbfe9 _ZNK4objc8DenseMapIP11objc_objectmLb1ENS_12DenseMapInfoIS2_EENS3_ImEEE15LookupBucketForERKS2_RPNSt3__14pairIS2_mEE + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915fc60 free + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9915fd2d free + 214
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbca9b objc_destructInstance + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbcada objc_destructInstance + 72
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fc4f2a _object_dispose + 8
  0   Foundation                          0x9222c3cc -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fc4f61 _object_dispose + 63
  0   HIToolbox                           0x9122a041 ReleaseEvent + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbd184 object_dispose + 6
  0   AppKit                              0x9393d05e -[NSEvent dealloc] + 9
  0   AppKit                              0x9393d1bb -[NSEvent dealloc] + 358
  0   AppKit                              0x9385e101 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 12
  0   AppKit                              0x9385e167 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 114
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbaabc objc_msgSend + 76
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbd43d _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 485
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbd264 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 12
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914abd3 __mtx_droplock + 442
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b57f pthread_mutex_unlock + 287
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbd35 unlockForMethodLookup + 5
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b57f pthread_mutex_unlock + 287
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbab3 _cache_fill + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b469 pthread_mutex_unlock + 9
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbba9d log_and_fill_cache + 127
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbd35 unlockForMethodLookup + 5
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbd61 unlockForMethodLookup + 49
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb46b lookUpMethod + 389
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb2ef lookUpMethod + 9
  0   AppKit                              0x93854281 -[NSApplication run] + 12
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb2dc _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 42
  0   AppKit                              0x93854281 -[NSApplication run] + 12
  0   AppKit                              0x938545c7 -[NSApplication run] + 850
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbab3 _cache_fill + 9
  0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9914b469 pthread_mutex_unlock + 9
  0   AppKit                              0x93854281 -[NSApplication run] + 12
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbbd61 unlockForMethodLookup + 49
  0   AppKit                              0x93854519 -[NSApplication run] + 676
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x95fbb46b lookUpMethod + 389
```

Comment: Post the crash report; in particular, the stack trace that leads to the crash. For what it’s worth, that method is called when a rich-text text view selection is copied to the pasteboard.

Comment: I've added the callstack.

Comment: The three-finger tap it is! Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `NSTextInputClient` methods can be called by any input method. Whether an input method does call it or not is an implementation detail. Just pointing out that whatever solution you try to implement should not be specific to the Look Up action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the trace includes the Lookup framework, try using the lookup feature. Select a word in your view and three-finger tap it if you’re using a trackpad, or right-click it and choose Look Up in the contextual menu.